# Пересортировать по 4 элемента

Tags: javascript, php

Помогите, пожалуйста, пересортировать элементы. Элементы выводятся в таком порядке

```
<div class="row block-tabs">
    <div class="col-25 tab" data-item-id="175">1</div>
    <div class="col-100 desc" data-desc-id="175">1</div>
    <div class="col-25 tab" data-item-id="176">2</div>
    <div class="col-100 desc" data-desc-id="176">2</div>
    <div class="col-25 tab" data-item-id="177">3</div>
    <div class="col-100 desc" data-desc-id="177">3</div>
    <div class="col-25 tab" data-item-id="178">4</div>
    <div class="col-100 desc" data-desc-id="178">4</div>
    <div class="col-25 tab" data-item-id="179">5</div>
    <div class="col-100 desc" data-desc-id="179">5</div>
    <div class="col-25 tab" data-item-id="180">6</div>
    <div class="col-100 desc" data-desc-id="180">6</div>
    <div class="col-25 tab" data-item-id="181">7</div>
    <div class="col-100 desc" data-desc-id="181">7</div>
</div>
```

Необходимо получить в таком

```
<div class="row block-tabs">
    <div class="col-25 tab" data-item-id="175">1</div>
    <div class="col-25 tab" data-item-id="176">2</div>
    <div class="col-25 tab" data-item-id="177">3</div>
    <div class="col-25 tab" data-item-id="178">4</div>
    <div class="col-100 desc" data-desc-id="175">1</div>
    <div class="col-100 desc" data-desc-id="176">2</div>
    <div class="col-100 desc" data-desc-id="177">3</div>
    <div class="col-100 desc" data-desc-id="178">4</div>
    <div class="col-25 tab" data-item-id="179">5</div>
    <div class="col-25 tab" data-item-id="180">6</div>
    <div class="col-25 tab" data-item-id="181">7</div>
    <div class="col-100 desc" data-desc-id="179">5</div>
    <div class="col-100 desc" data-desc-id="180">6</div>
    <div class="col-100 desc" data-desc-id="181">7</div>
</div>
```

Или может вы мне поможете правильно написать цикл вывода

```
<? foreach($list as $item) : ?>
<div class="col-25 tab" data-item-id="<?=$item->id?>">
    ...
</div>
<div class="col-100 desc" data-desc-id="<?=$item->id?>">
    ...
</div>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Я уже всю голову сломал пытаясь понять как можно манипулировать итерациями в цикле и выводить по очереди по четыре элемента, при этом сначала выводить четыре tab, потом возвращаться назад и выводить четыре desc с теме же id, потом продолжать и снова возвращаться.
Количество блоков может быть любое, но они всегда парные (tab и desc) и должны сортироваться по не более четырём.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы оперировать итерациями, сперва нужно подготовить массив.

```
$arr = [
    [ 'id' => 1 ],
    [ 'id' => 2 ],
    [ 'id' => 3 ],
    [ 'id' => 4 ],
    [ 'id' => 5 ],
    [ 'id' => 6 ],
    [ 'id' => 7 ],
    [ 'id' => 8 ],
];
function prepare(array &$array, int $num): void {
    // разбиваем массив по $num эл-тов
    $array = array_chunk($array, $num); 
    $array = array_map(function($item){
        // удваиваем кол-во эл-тов у каждом "разбитом" массиве
        return array_merge($item, $item); 
    }, $array);
}

prepare($arr, 4);

foreach($arr as $idx => $item){
    // разбиваем массив по 4 эл-та т.к. при подготовке мы их удваивали
    $item = array_chunk($item, 4); 
    foreach($item as $k => $i ) {
        // проходим "уже разбитый" массив циклом, и определяем тип (tab, desc) 
        // для четных\не четных эл-тов
        $sub =  $k % 2 === 0 ? "tab" : "desc";
        foreach($i as $subItem) {
            echo $sub . " => " . $subItem['id'] . "\n";
        }       
    }
}
```

[Пример в песочнице](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/78c4d039041aed32666137b66f52b5cbb747c784)

Comment: Честно признаюсь, я так и не понял как это применить. Для чего там массив $arr и как его забить динамически, ведь блоков может быть сколько угодно. Как мне туда внедрить свой массив, из которого я вывожу. Но за array_chunk() - спасибо. С его помощью я сделал то, что работает.